# How do I send an AT command in minicom or cu?

Tags: serial-port

How I can send a command to a USB/COM device? I set up a port in minicom to /dev/ttyUSB0 and run:

```
sudo minicom
```

After this command I try to enter an `AT` command, but I get unreadable symbols in the terminal:

```
Добро пожаловать в minicom 2.7

ПАРАМЕТРЫ: I18n                                                              
Дата компиляции Jan  1 2014, 17:13:19.                                       
Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 21:18:08                                                  

Нажмите CTRL-A Z для получения подсказки по клавишам                         

�
```

I also tried the cu program, but I got the same result - unreadable symbols when I type `AT`:

```
$ sudo cu -l ttyUSB0
Connected.
��
```

What I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: Incidentally, are those unreadable? Looks like Russian to me - Parameter: I18n, etc - I take it from your name that you aren't using Minicom in English & we're just looking at that one final character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't told it what baud rate (speed) the port is running at.

`sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0`
gets

`speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel`

on my system - default of 9600 baud.

Minicom, IIRC, defaults to 115200.

There is a good chance your device isn't using that speed. If you're sending AT commands it's a fair bet you're looking at a modem, in which case 9600 would be an antique model; try setting 115200 or 38400 baud. Without knowing what device you have it's pointless trying to talk about changing it's setting!

You will, then, need to play with the PC end - unless you know what speed your device uses. `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 38400` will set your USB to 38400; in Minicom, it's -A then Z then O to get the menu you want. You can try guessing, it won't break anything.

Comment: I set baud rate to 38400 and get answer to some at commands: `>ati ELM327 v1.5` but `at` command return `?`. May be it's devise problem?

Comment: You have now got it talking to you - try some other commands, see what helps - it's DECADES since I used AT commands! I think ATI followed by a number expands on the info given?

Comment: Also, ELM327 - it's a car OBD-II dongle! Try it with some specific software to test it - there is some out there, I have one myself.. but normally use a phone app.

Comment: Yes, I can talk with it, but it's not support all commands from specification http://elmelectronics.com/ELM327/AT_Commands.pdf (it's clone of ELM327) I can't find any obd-2 software in ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I think it was a download, google it - I'm just going out, sorry! There is definitely something to be found.